# Cannot avoid override property for each element inside a loop?

Tags: java, loops

I have an issue. There is an object with a list of elements...

I have a for looping on the list and then I do this

```
for (Object myObject : myObjects) {
    myObject.setProperty(someService.getMyPropertyById(id));
}
```

Seems like it overrides all the elements by a last element property.

I also tried creating a fresh list before the for and then add `myNewList.add(myObject)` with the hope to avoid this but same result.

Any idea how to archieve this? Sounds quite easy but im struggling a little bit.

After a while I realized the property (only one has this issue) gets wipped out at the second buble of my for, even if the object was already added to a new list and should not be modified... it gets modified.

Comment: What's `id` in `getMyPropertyById(id)`? I think you need to change that too with loop.

Comment: is myObject.id , should change with each loop, but i dont know why all seems to be working on the very same object

Answer (score 0):

I believe the id should be increasing too, something like this

```
for (int index = 0; index < myObjects.size; index++) { 
  myObjects.get(index).setProperty(someService.getMyPropertyById(index);
}
```

Comment: After debugging I realized when enters to my 2nd bucle it deletes that var, I dont know why, even if were added to a list, thi s is the most bizzare behaviour evern seen

Comment: Actually, I'm still unclear about the situation. Can you explain me more clearly?

Comment: in my loop it sets the properties for the first one, then, the second loop sets the property of the first one as null (setting it like myObject.setProperty()...

Comment: It might be because `someService.getMyPropertyById(id)` is null or the id is null.